# Prevent Iframe to load from certain domains

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe

is there a way to prevent an Iframe to load resources from certain domains?

On my website I have embed videos from vimeo.com.
But playing these videos connections are made to

- akamaized.net (XHR)
- gravatar.com (pic)
- wp.com (pic)
- google-analytics

If I block these services locally on my browser with uMatrix all videos still play without any issues.

Ideally I want to make sure these domains do not get contacted when visiting my site or watching the embeded videos.

I tried iframe atribute sandbox, but videos do not get played.

Also tried using Security Headers:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: *vimeo.com/* *vimeocdn.com/*; img-src 'self' http: https: *vimeo.com/* *vimeocdn.com/*;script-src http: https: img-src 'self' http: https: *vimeo.com/* *vimeocdn.com/*; frame-ancestors img-src 'self' http: https: *vimeo.com/* *vimeocdn.com/*; style-src img-src 'self' http: https: *vimeo.com/* *vimeocdn.com/*"
```

But the domains above still get contacted...

Comment: The "free video content" and bandwidth that vimeo provides is financed by ads/analytics/etc.  I believe that if you use a paid subscription to vimeo (vimeo pro or something) you have the option of embedding "clean" video in your website, a fair trade-off.  Please see [this question to vimeo support](https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:267016) for more info.

Comment: So there is no way to prevent an iframe from loading content from specific websites?

Comment: Nope.  Your javascript won't have access to modify the frame content, and your server has nothing to do with what that frame serves up.